# Use prism/mef without MefBootstrapper

Tags: prism, mef

I want to use some assemblies containing views and viewmodels exported using prism/mef in some other program. This other program does not contain a custom MefBootstrapper (since it does not use mef).

Creating the catalog and container is easy, but when I call Container.GetExportedValue() I always get null as result even though SomeView exists in the container (I looked).

I guess I need this part of the custom MefBootstrapper:

```
protected override Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions.IRegionBehaviorFactory ConfigureDefaultRegionBehaviors()
{
  var factory = base.ConfigureDefaultRegionBehaviors();
  factory.AddIfMissing("AutoPopulateExportedViewsBehavior", typeof(AutoPopulateExportedViewsBehavior));
  return factory;
}
```

But how and where do I call this when I don't use a MefBootstrapper?

Comment: Can you post the code that is trying to get the export, and maybe the code where the part is being exported?